# Is a tree proof or natural deduction a semantic method of proof?

Tags: proof, philosophy-of-logic, semantics, dummett

[Peter Schroeder-Heister writes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/#InfIntAntRea) in an article on "Proof-Theoretic Semantics" the following:

> Proof-theoretic semantics is inherently inferential, as it is inferential activity which manifests itself in proofs. It thus belongs to *inferentialism* (see Brandom, 2000) according to which inferences and the rules of inference establish the meaning of expressions, in contradistinction to *denotationalism*, according to which denotations are the primary sort of meaning. Inferentialism and the ‘meaning-as-use’ view of semantics is the broad philosophical framework of proof-theoretic semantics.

He also notes:

> According to Dummett, the logical position of intuitionism corresponds to the philosophical position of anti-realism. The realist view of a recognition independent reality is the metaphysical counterpart of the view that all sentences are either true or false independent of our means of recognizing it. Following Dummett, major parts of proof-theoretic semantics are associated with anti-realism.

I previously thought of natural deduction or tree proofs as syntactic proof techniques, however, I wonder if that is accurate given the above. If so, that would seem to leave axiomatic proofs as the only syntactic proof technique.

Given proof-theoretic semantics are tree proofs or natural deduction *semantic* proof techniques? Or does that only apply if one accepts Dummett's anti-realism?

---

Schroeder-Heister, Peter, "Proof-Theoretic Semantics", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Spring 2018 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2018/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/.

Comment: "Syntactic"/"semantic" labels are typically used with the Tarskian semantics in mind, they are not relativized to one's semantics. So something that strings together inference rules is "syntactic", and something that constructs a set-theoretic model is "semantic". It gets vague if "syntactic" proofs are so structured that one can transparently extract a model out of them, as with some tree proofs. Hintikka et al. call those "semantic methods", see [Anellis, From semantic tableaux to Smullyan trees](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rml/1204834539).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Frederick Suppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Suppe) in his entry *Axiomatization* from [*A Companion to the Philosophy of Science*](https://www.abebooks.com/9780631170242/Companion-Philosophy-Science-Blackwell-Companions-0631170243/plp), syntactical and semantic approaches to 
axiomatization are both possible formally, semiformally, or informally.

What differentiates syntactic versus semantic approaches is the degree by which the axiomatic system is devoid of propositional content. Thus, the logical positivists who started out looking for a syntactic approach for truth, ultimately fell back on observational vocabulary (what Quine calls observational sentences in *The Two Dogmas of Science*) as a method of formal semantics, such as in [Ramsey sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_sentence).

From page 9:

> On semantical approaches one identifies an intended class C of systems or instances, then presents a formal structure S... [such that] S is specified axiomatically, indicating that axiomatization is not the exclusive possession of syntactical approaches.

So, as I read this, it is not so much the logical organization of the approach which determines its characterization, but rather how tightly coupled semantic content is to the model. Euclid's Elements is an informal semantic approach because the axioms and postulates of his method clearly have meaning, where as in model theory when a model based on sentential calculus is used to prove Gödel's incompleteness theorems, the meaning of the approach is confined to the abstraction itself.

EDIT

In this way, natural deduction is semantic because it uses natural language which possess content, as are proof trees because they speak to the meaning of logical operations. I would see this as being complementary to the realist methodology because instead of attacking theories from a structural standpoint divorced from meaning as a mere tool for exploring theory, it actually establishes meaningful explanations of observations? (I'm open to criticism.)